# Assign Lists/Tuples with do notation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a function f that goes something like this:

```
f = do
      x1 <- g
      x2 <- g
      x3 <- g
      ...
      xn <- g
      return [x1,x2,x3,..., xn] --or (x1,x2,x3,..., xn)
```

This requires many lines of code and I have a feeling this can be done prettier.
I would like to know if there is a way to do something like this:

```
f = do
      [x,y,z] <- [g,g,g]
      return [x,y,z]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3asequence) and [`replicate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3areplicate):

```
f = do
    xs <- sequence $ replicate n g
    return xs
```

Comment: Thanks! This led me to an even prettier solution. You don't need sequence if you use replicateM.

Comment: Really just `seqeuence $ replicate n g`. The `do` syntax is entirely extraneous here.

Comment: In the example it is, but I do much more in my code than just return the list.

Answer (score 7):

A simpler version of @Zeta's solution is:

```
import Control.Monad

f = replicateM n g
```